# Limit the range of numeric values of field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to **limit the range of values** that a numeric field could have.
ex. The field "year" should be able to have values from 1995 to 2016

Is this possible in **Transact-SQL for Microsoft SQL Server 2012** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a [CHECK CONSTRAINT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), like this:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
    Id int not null primary key,
    Year int not null check (Year >= 1995 AND Year <= 2016)
)
```